# Why does the singly linked list print "NULL"?

Tags: c, singly-linked-list

I wrote a code that prints words in array of a singly linked list. But when I run the code, it will print `(null)` but not `JAN`. I have no idea why it keeps printing `null`. Can anyone helps me?

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct LLNode
{
    char *CharArr[10];
    struct LLNode *next;
};

struct LLNode * createNode (char val[])
{
    struct LLNode *temp;
    temp =(struct LLNode *)malloc(sizeof(struct LLNode));
    temp-> CharArr[10] = val;
    temp-> next = NULL;
    return (temp) ;
};

int main ()
{
    struct LLNode *head = NULL;
    struct LLNode *curr = NULL;
    //char a[10]="JAN";

    head = curr = createNode ("JAN") ;
    printf ("curr->CharArr[10] = %s\n", curr->CharArr[10]) ;
}
```

Comment: In your own words: what do you expect `curr->CharArr[10]` to mean?

Comment: Also: when you declare `char *CharArr[10]` in the struct, what do you expect the struct will contain?

Answer (score 1):

Out of range indexing. Your program is undefined but it reduced to something really simple.

```
    temp-> CharArr[10] = val;
    temp-> next = NULL;
```

`CharArr` only has ten elements, and you wrote to the non-extant tenth element, so when you wrote to `temp->next` you overwrote `val`.

Maybe you think arrays are indexed from 1 to n, but they're indexed from 0 to n.

To see this work, change `char *CharArr[10];` to `char *CharArr[11];`. But you probably want to reconsider that type altogether. It looks like you meant `char CharArr[10];` and populate it by calling `strcpy` (`#include <string.h>`).

Comment: Oh, so if I want to let `val` being written, then I should consider `CharArr[(n-1)]` after I initialize `char *CharArr[n]` (n can be any number). Is that correct?

Comment: @lyhsuan01: Correct.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve with `CharArr`: either your node carries the data, and you get rid of the pointer to the char array, or you want it to be a pointer to another region where the string lives, and get rid of the array part.

First version, where the node contains the characters:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct LLNode
{
    char *CharArr[10];
    struct LLNode *next;
};

struct LLNode * createNode (char val[])
{
    struct LLNode *temp;
    temp =(struct LLNode *)malloc(sizeof(struct LLNode));
    temp-> CharArr[10] = val;
    temp-> next = NULL;
    return (temp) ;
};

int main ()
{
    struct LLNode *head = NULL;
    struct LLNode *curr = NULL;

    head = curr = createNode ("JAN") ;
    printf ("curr->CharArr[10] = %s\n", curr->CharArr[10]) ;
}
```

Second version, pointing to a region outside the Node:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct LLNode
{
    char *CharArr;
    struct LLNode *next;
};

struct LLNode * createNode (char val[])
{
    struct LLNode *temp;
    temp =(struct LLNode *)malloc(sizeof(struct LLNode));
    temp->CharArr = strdup(val);
    temp-> next = NULL;
    return (temp) ;
};

int main ()
{
    struct LLNode *head = NULL;
    struct LLNode *curr = NULL;
    //char a[10]="JAN";

    head = curr = createNode ("JAN") ;
    printf ("curr->CharArr = %s\n", curr->CharArr) ;
}
```

Notice that in both cases, no cleanup is done on the node. In the second version, you also need to `free()` the `CharArr`.

See valgind output:

```
$ valgrind ./so 
==19670== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==19670== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==19670== Using Valgrind-3.15.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==19670== Command: ./so
==19670== 
curr->CharArr = JAN
==19670== 
==19670== HEAP SUMMARY:
==19670==     in use at exit: 20 bytes in 2 blocks
==19670==   total heap usage: 3 allocs, 1 frees, 1,044 bytes allocated
==19670== 
==19670== LEAK SUMMARY:
==19670==    definitely lost: 16 bytes in 1 blocks
==19670==    indirectly lost: 4 bytes in 1 blocks
==19670==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==19670==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==19670==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==19670== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==19670== 
==19670== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==19670== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: Hmm... Actually I want to define a `struct` that includes a character array of size 10 (to store a string) and a pointer to link to the next node. But if I get rid the pointer of `char *CharArr[10]`, it will shows (null) too.